# Is there a significant difference in flavor between black and white truffles?

Tags: mushrooms, truffles

I've tried both black and white truffles on separate occasions, but never side by side.  Is there a meaningful difference between the two as far as flavor is concerned?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, yes there is.

Black truffles are dark, earthy, *sexy* in flavour. Renaissance writings compare them to 'unwashed slatterns' and 'bedchambers, rooms of sexual congress, unaired and reeking of the recent activities contained therein.'

White truffles are lighter in aroma and flavour, with distinct garlicky notes. Each has their place--black works better on its own, white works better as an adjunt or finishing note to a dish. I am personally partial to white truffle oil drizzled on cured duck breast, or a black truffle risotto with charred endive.

Comment: mmmmm, reeking of unwashed slatterns... That's a heck of a description, +1

Comment: lols: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slatterns Where do you find such writing?

Comment: i honestly cannot remember. i ran across the phrasing years ago and, for tolerably obvious reasons, it stuck in my head.

Comment: I'll take a punnet of the black ones then please.